# Using Stokes Theorem on a bunch of line segments

Tags: surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Here's an example of what I mean:
Let $$\vec{F} = \bigg(\frac{2z}{1+y}+\sin(x^2),\frac{3z}{1+x}+\sin(y^2),5(x+1)(y+2)\bigg)$$ and $C$ be the oriented curve consisting of four line segments from $(0,0,0)$ to $(2,0,0)$, from $(2,0,0)$ to $(0,0,2)$, from $(0,0,2)$ to $(0,3,0)$ and from $(0,3,0)$ to $(0,0,0)$.

How would I implement stokes' theorem to solve for the work integral $\int_C \vec{F}d\vec{r}$? (assuming Stoke's Theorem is applicable here...)

Comment: why do you want to use the Stoke’s Theorem here? usually the stokes theorem is used in the reverse case, i.e., when given the curl of a vector on an area, you reduce it to a line integral on the boundary to simplify calculations. Here you already have a line integral

Comment: The orientated curve effectively spans 2 triangles. Apply Green's Theorem (which is just Stoke's Theorem in $R^2$) to each triangle (making sure you maintain the correct orientation stipulated by Green's Theorem). Note that the two triangles share a side that is not part of the curve. You may still use Green's Theorem on each triangle as the two-line integrals from each computation along said line segment will cancel due to orientation. Then, simply add the results from each computation and reverse the sign (Green's Theorem requires an orientation opposite from the one given in the question).

Comment: Though I agree with ravjotsk in this case. I would just compute the line integral directly.

Comment: Stokes's theorem is very useful, but it's something I learned in my second year of university. That is to say, it's not at all niche, and there are plenty of resources online, and plenty of textbooks, which discuss it. Perhaps those have failed you, but from the wording of the question it sounds like you haven't searched anywhere for an explanation of the theorem, or how to apply it. I urge you to do so, as any result here will more than likely be a near identical explanation as one given in any of these online resources of textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some hint (expect some calculation mistakes).

By Stokes' theorem
$$\oint_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\iint_S\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{n}dS$$
where $\hat{n}$ is the positive (outward drawn) normal to the surface $S$.

If you trace out the line segments, you would get a surface $S=S_1\cup S_2$ where $S_1$ is a triangle on the $yz$-plane with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,2)$ and $(0,3,0)$ and $S_2$ is a triangle on the $xz$-plane with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$.

Now one can write $\iint_S\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{n}dS$ as $\iint_{S_1}\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{n}dS_1+\iint_{S_2}\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{n}dS_2$ and note that on $S_1$, $\hat{n}=\hat{i}$ and on $S_2$, $\hat{n}=\hat{j}$.

$$\nabla\times\vec{F}=\left(5(x+1)-\frac{3}{1+x}\right)\hat{i}+\left(\frac{2}{1+y}-5(y+2)\right)\hat{j}+\frac{z}{(1+x)^2}\hat{k}.$$

Then the line integral equals
\begin{align}
\iint_{S_1}\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{i}dS_1+\iint_{S_2}\big(\nabla\times\vec{F}\big)\cdot\hat{j}dS_2=\iint_{S_1}\left(5(x+1)-\frac{3}{1+x}\right)dydz+\iint_{S_2}\left(\frac{2}{1+y}-5(y+2)\right)dxdz
\end{align}
Now we can calculate these two surface integrals as double integrals with appropriate limits of integration.